# How to set the Airprint orientation to Landscape in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiinterfaceorientation, airprint

I have to send an Airprint my WebView in landscape mode. 
But I am getting error while setting up my orientation.
I have written this code

```
    let printcontroller = UIPrintInteractionController.sharedPrintController()
    let printinfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary:nil)
    printinfo.jobName = "Printing Label"
    printinfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputType.General
    printcontroller.printInfo = printinfo
    printinfo.orientation = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight
    printcontroller.printFormatter = myWeb.viewPrintFormatter()
    printcontroller.showsNumberOfCopies = false
    printcontroller.presentAnimated(true) { (_, isPrinted, error) in
        if error == nil
        {
            if isPrinted
            {
                print ("Printed Successfully")
            }   else
            {
                print ("Printing failed")
            }

        }
    }
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("finaltohome", sender: nil)
```

[image]

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It's enums now: `UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft` or `UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight`. And you need to `import UIKit`.

Answer (score 0):

`UIPrintInfo` has its own orientation enum `UIPrintInfoOrientation` which has two value, portrait or landscape.

```
printinfo.orientation = UIPrintInfoOrientation.landscape
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following:

```
`let printInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary:nil)
 printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputType.general
 printInfo.jobName = "print Job"
 printInfo.orientation = .landscape
 printController.printInfo = printInfo`
```